# Argo workflows Result and error are unresolved

Tags: argo-workflows, argo

I ran the argo workflow pipeline
Is there any fix on this DEBUG error message or this is a knows issue?

DEBU[2023-10-30T11:33:26.690Z] Result and error are unresolved               error="cannot fetch check-schema from  (1:15)\n | jsonpath(tasks['check-schema'].outputs.parameters.output, '$.table_name') \n | ..............^"
DEBU[2023-10-30T11:33:26.690Z] Result and error are unresolved               error="cannot fetch check-schema from  (1:15)\n | jsonpath(tasks['check-schema'].outputs.parameters.output, '$.table_name') \n | ..............^"

Thank you

Is this possible to fix?